# working with many FXML file

Tags: java, javafx, project, scenebuilder

I am working in project that has tabpane and 8 label with action when i click on any label it will load tab from FXML file and then add it to main tabpane and so on.

I worked in project that has one layout and it easy with that but in my case it will be many FXML files that contain layouts, this is new for me.

And then load Main menu associate withe tab to another tabpane.
also i want when user click on one option in main menu the content of main tab will append with some extra option.

Here some image of what i want to do :

*here is the home page build with scene builder*

[image]

*here what happen when user click on label and if he click on option menu*

[image]

I am just start javafx early and i want to know how to do something like that.
If someone know or have any idea how to do this or any source code to understand this.

thank's

edit:
here what i have tried but i get nullPointerException.

this is main class that load home page.

```
package fxml;


import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            FXMLLoader root = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/fxml/One.fxml"));
            AnchorPane home = root.load();
            Scene s2 = new Scene(home);
            primaryStage.setScene(s2);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

the firstClass that linked with the home layout

```
package fxml;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.TabPane;

public class FirstLayout {
    @FXML
    TabPane content;
    SecondLayout S = new SecondLayout();

public void onclick(){
    S.load();
    content.getTabs().add(S.gettab());
    System.out.println("Done");
}
}
```

the second class that represent tab will add to tabpane in home layout when click button

```
package fxml;

import java.io.IOException;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.control.Tab;

public class SecondLayout extends Tab {


@FXML private Tab t;

public SecondLayout() {

}


public void load(){
    FXMLLoader load = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/fxml/Two.fxml"));
    load.setRoot(this);
    load.setController(this);
    try {
        load.load();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Error");
    }
}

public Tab gettab(){
    return t;
}

}
```

Comment: By your code I was thinking about an example like I did not all your project ;)

Comment: no no not like you do , Your code is not for my case

Comment: Here is a similar query and its answer might be of some help to you - [Perfect way to use FXMLs](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2598756)

Comment: sorry for saying that but i do not fully understand the answer of this article, for example 
currentSubMenuController.set((SubMenuController)loader.getController());
 i do not know what it is and way use it !!!!!!!!!!!!!
but the article is same thing and it sound great

Comment: `SecondLayout` looks strange: it is a subclass of `Tab` but also has a reference to a `Tab`? Why? Can you post the FXML file `Two.fxml` (or at least enough to show what is going on) in your question? And also post the full stack trace and identify which line is throwing the exception.

Comment: i know it is strange but this is last try i did , so i post it as you see. i will add what you want. Thank you for caring.

Comment: sorry for that but i deleted project , but i remembered that error come from try and catch in secondLayout class (load) function . please if you know another and best way to do what i want help me , i hope that I explained what i want clear for you !!!

Answer (score 0):

Usually, it is recommended to have several FXML files, one for each module. Given your screenshots, I can see that all your areas seems to be linked, so having only one FXML file seems the best idea. But, maybe if you change a bit your architecture you could have several FXML files.

To sum up : best practice is to have the most independant features as possible and one FXML by feature. If making a static variable is solving a strong dependency a enable you to make several FXML files, which is easier to understand so I would say do it.

I am quite new to JavaFX too, but as far as I've tried it out, it seems to be the best solution for me. 
However if a JavaFX expert is here and says I'm wrong, I would accept a better solution with great pleasure

For your question, I don't know if you can load a FXML file dynamically, but I am 100% sure you can change the layout with the listener you will attach to your FXML file

UPDATE : Here is an example file
FXML File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane?>

<Pane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.91" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="controller.AcquireButtonListener">
   <children>
      <Button fx:id="leaveButton" layoutX="707.0" layoutY="24.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#leaveApp" text="Leave App" />
   </children>
</Pane>
```

And the Java file associated

```
package controller;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;

public class AcquireButtonListener {

    private Button leaveButton;

    @FXML
    protected void leaveApp(ActionEvent event){
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: thank's for your replay, but I did as you say the home page  is connected with one controller and other layout loaded in this page , but my problem as i said too many  FXML file and one controller if i connected these to one controller i get NullpointerException  and i do not know why , but i asked the best way to do this.
thak's again

Comment: I will update my answer, providing you an example for fxml file, however, could you give your code (at least the FXML file and the stack trace) in order we can help you

Comment: i will update question provide the project code and what i have done